# Students who have taken the test for every course in their degree

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been trying to do a "Not exist" approach to isolate the answer, but I think I've gone a bit too deep. I'm limited to essentially only using like really basic stuff for my intro to database class. So, basically only INNER JOIN, UNION, and CASE and maybe a few other stuff, but probably best assume like the bare bones stuff. We're not allowed to use coalesce yet.

Comment: how did stu002 manage to take an exam this isnt in a course?

Comment: since we don't see from the question if there is a course table or not "Calc C" might exist, but not be mandatory for any specific program?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible with just  INNER JOIN, UNION, and CASE -> but I found a solution with an outer join (still quite simple).

Lets try to solve this in two steps.

1) Lets see which students have NOT finished all their classes

```
select s.code
  from  programs p inner join students s on (p.degree = s.degree)
                   left outer join exams e on (e.course = p.course and e.student = s.code)
  where e.course is null
```

We join programs with students and then left outer join the exams and filter only those rows where no exam row could be matched (which means the student has not taken the exam yet)

2) We get all students that are NOT returned by this query (meaning they have finished all required courses)

```
select
code, name
from student where code not in (

  select s.code
  from  programs p inner join students s on (p.degree = s.degree)
                   left outer join exams e on (e.course = p.course and e.student = s.code)
  where e.course is null

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using aggregation for these things.

```
select s.code, s.name, s.degree
from students s join
     programs p
     on p.degree = s.degree join
     exams e
     on e.student = s.code and e.course = p.course
group by s.code, s.name, s.degree
having count(distinct e.course) = (select count(*) from programs p2 where p2.degree = p.degree);
```

Note that this includes the `degree` as well as the student.  After all, students could double major.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar vein to Preli's answer, I'd use a left join to highlight exams that had not been taken:

```
SELECT s.code, s.name, p.course
FROM
  students s
  INNER JOIN
  programs p 
  ON (p.degree = s.degree)
```

This is effectively the list of exams a student must take for the course

Now add on the exams they have taken, and leave nulls for those they havent:

```
SELECT s.code, s.name, p.course, e.course
FROM
  students s
  INNER JOIN
  programs p 
  ON (p.degree = s.degree)

  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  exams e
  ON e.student = s.code AND e.course = p.course
```

The results would look like:

```
Code   | Name | p.Course | e.Course
stu001 | John | Calc A   | Calc A
stu001 | John | Calc B   | Calc B
stu002 | Doe  | Calc A   | <null>
stu002 | Doe  | Calc B   | <null>
```

Now reduce it to a list of just students that have taken an exam for every course. We can do this by checking that the COUNT(e.course) is the same as the COUNT(p.course) because NULL isn't counted by COUNT() so any occurrences of null (no exam) in e.course reduce the count, compared to counting the overall occurrences of p.course (i could also have used count(*)):

```
SELECT s.code, s.name
FROM
  students s
  INNER JOIN
  programs p 
  ON (p.degree = s.degree)

  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  exams e
  ON e.student = s.code AND e.course = p.course

GROUP BY s.code, s.name
HAVING COUNT(p.course) = COUNT(e.course)
```

John's COUNT(p.Course) would be 2 and COUNT(e.course) would also be 2, so he shows (just once, because he's grouped. Doe's COUNT(p.course) is 2 but COUNT(e.course) is 0, because all values are null, and 2 != 0 so he is hidden